# What is the strength of a stationary costationary subset of $\omega_1$?

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice

It is known that it consistent with $\mathsf{ZF}$ that there are no disjoint stationary subsets of $\omega_1$.

Is the assertion "there exist a stationary costationary subset of $\omega_1$" equivalent to, or does it imply/is it implied by some weak form of choice or some other more "standard" statement over $\mathsf{ZF}$? I couldn't find anything similar in Rubin and Howard standard reference "consequences of the axiom of choice" (in fact unless my pdf reader is badly broken the word "stationary" is *never* used in the book, which was a big surprise to me!)

Comment: Short answer: if you assume DC, or even countable choice, so that the club filter is in fact a measure, by the work of Mitchell you have a $\kappa^+$ repeat point in an inner model. Without assuming any closure on the ultrafilter, Spector had an argument to get this from ZFC, but the argument is false, and we have no idea how to fix this. I routine go back to this problem with Yair Hayut, and we take new ideas, and nothing comes out at the end. So it's still very much open, much to the dismay of many.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Ah of course, I should have thought about rephrasing the question in terms of the club filter, searching the site for "costationary" and similar keywords brought up nothing relevant. I'm reading your answer to the other question, thanks for the link, very interesting stuff. I find it surprising that so little is known though, that's annoying!

Comment: Yes. Arthur Apter set me loose on that question almost five years ago. The whole critical cardinals project came out of that... http://karagila.org/2018/critical-cardinals/

Comment: Every time you comment or answer one of my questions on this site I end up with a mountain of interesting stuff to read @AsafKaragila

Comment: You're welcome.